# inserted Data on MongoDb without ObjectId but I want it

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

When I'm inserting data to MongoDB it look like this..

```
_id: "611ddfb55c0ca9fe6df6ae6e"
name:"Residential Real Estate Photography"
price:"989"
```

without ObjectID,
But I wanted it to be with ObjectId
How to solve this?

Comment: An id is automatically added _id. Object id wich id you're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The `_id` field in the MongoDB document is always `ObjectID`.

If you are talking about getting the value as an object of type `ObjectID`, you have to convert the string.

For js you can use https://github.com/williamkapke/bson-objectid
To get from string simply do `var id = (ObjectID("611ddfb55c0ca9fe6df6ae6e"));`